# Getting only polygon boundaries from latitude and longitude

Tags: coordinate-system, google-maps

**Problem Statement:**

I am working on the project where machines are sending huge amount of lat/long data. Now I am drawing multiple days data on a map, it takes too much time to draw complete data on the map. 
We are saving data in Influxdb.

**My Propose Solution**

My solution is to only draw empty polygons on the map. I want to calculate/get  boundaries of an area with latitude and longitude. I will save those boundaries lat/long in a separate table for fast rendering on the map. I will use those boundaries data to draw the polygon in google map.

**Question**

How to get red marked boundary of area, which is mentioned in below image. I would prefer a backend library so that my service can calculate these boundaries and save in Influxdb.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps convexhull.

Comment: @FelixIP Thanks, your tip works, I solved using convexhull method

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're looking for a bounding box. Find the following points: SW, NW, NE, SE. If you have ArcMap available you may find results in using a minimum bounding geometry.